# Can we use Groovy Template Engine in Grails Framework(GGTS)?

Tags: templates, grails, groovy, playframework

I am planning to convert a project from play1.2.5( Java Based) to Grails framework and in the html files we have used Groovy template engine to generate html components.

Can we use Groovy Template Engine in Grails Framework(GGTS)? Is it already provided by Grails Framework or do we need to integrate that template engine in grails framework...If we need to integrate it, then how to do that?

Does anyone have experience about this?Can you please share your knowledge.

I really appreciate your help!

Thanks!

Comment: You used the [Markup Template Engine](http://groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.3.2/html/documentation/markup-template-engine.html)?